# Error When Sending Files via DM with Slack's files_upload_v2()

Tags: python, slack-api

Slack recommends migrating from `files_upload()` to `files_upload_v2()` for stability relating to large files. However, this change means that you can no longer use something like `client.files_upload_v2(channel='@user.name', file=file)`. You can only send to a channel referenced by a channel ID. Is there a way to use the v2 function to send files as a DM (which would appear in the bot's Messages channel)? The details on v2 are explained [here](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/releases/tag/v3.19.0).

```
from slack_sdk import WebClient
token = MY_TOKEN
client = WebClient(token=token)
# works
response = client.files_upload(channels="@user.name", file="myfile.csv")


# fails
response = client.files_upload_v2(channels="@user.name", file="myfile.csv")
```

**Error:**

```
    SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed. (url: https://www.slack.com/api/files.completeUploadExternal)
    The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_arguments', 'response_metadata': {'messages': ['[ERROR] input must match regex pattern: ^[CGD][A-Z0-9]{8,}$ [json-pointer:/channel_id]']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not calling the username correctly, try `<@{username}>`

Comment: Thanks @hadar, but it's actually just a placeholder for the question, so the code works if I put in a real username. The question is whether there is a way to use the v2 function with a username so that it comes through as a DM, and not just for sending messages to channels.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a similar thing and the [Conversation API](https://api.slack.com/apis/conversations-api) helped my case.

Using [conversations.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open) API call with "users" field set, gives you the Channel ID for the Messages tab. I haven't seen it covered by the Python SDK, but making an HTTP request should work.

The response contains the Channel ID you can use:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "no_op": true,
    "already_open": true,
    "channel": {
        "id": "D069C7QFK",
        "created": 1460147748,
        "is_im": true,
        "is_org_shared": false,
        "user": "U069C7QF3",
        "last_read": "0000000000.000000",
        "latest": null,
        "unread_count": 0,
        "unread_count_display": 0,
        "is_open": true,
        "priority": 0
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, you need correct scopes AND "Messages" tab needs to be explicitly enabled in the Slack App's settings.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the Python SDK to call `conversations_list` to retrieve channel info. With that, create a map to decode the channel name to channel id for the `files_upload_v2()` call:

```
rez = client.conversations_list()
channel_name_to_id_map = {x['name']: x['id'] for x in rez['channels']}
```

Here is a link to the Slack documentation on conversations_list:
https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).